# Efficient alternatives to a Table based iteration

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, iterators

I have performed some operations using the Table iterator but I am looking for efficient alternatives to my approach.

First, some preliminary code:

```
(*Define functional forms of the mean and standard deviation for \
F(N/d) *)

model1bMean[Seq_, A1_, A2_, A3_] := A1 + A2 Log[Seq - A3];
model1bSD[B1_, B2_, Seq_] := Exp[B1 + B2 Log[Seq]];

(*Define pure functions for the mean and standard deviation of F(N/d)*)


model1bMean[#, 
   42.68082535273342`, -6.193871125474608`, -4.797231929767856`] &;
model1bSD[5.459440552945649`, -1.2914056750751017`, #] &;

(*verify that the mean and standard deviation function properly*)
meanValues1 = 
  model1bMean[#, 
     42.68082535273342`, -6.193871125474608`, -4.797231929767856`] & /@
    RandomReal[{40, 100}, 78];
sdValues1 = 
  model1bSD[5.459440552945649`, -1.2914056750751017`, #] & /@ 
   RandomReal[{10, 100}, 78];

meanValues2 = 
  model1bMean[#, 
     42.68082535273342`, -6.193871125474608`, -4.797231929767856`] & /@
    RandomReal[{50, 120}, 78];
sdValues2 = 
  model1bSD[5.459440552945649`, -1.2914056750751017`, #] & /@ 
   RandomReal[{5, 120}, 78];

(*simulate random values from the PDFs*)
nDist1 = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[#1, #2], 10^3] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{meanValues1, sdValues1}];
nDist2 = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[#1, #2], 10^3] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{meanValues2, sdValues2}];

circle = Range[10.^4, 10.^8, 10.^6];
```

Now the operations which i seek efficient alternatives are:

```
toCheck = Table[
   900000.00/nDist1[[x]] + circle[[y]]/nDist2[[x]],
   {x, 1, Length@nDist1},
   {y, 1, Length@circle}
   ];

distDD = Table[
   EmpiricalDistribution[toCheck[[x, y]]], {x, 1, 78}, {y, 1, 
    Length@circle}];

probData = 
  Table[NProbability[f >= 1, f \[Distributed] distDD[[x, y]]], {x, 1, 
    78}, {y, 1, Length@circle}];

dataToPlot = 
  Table[Transpose[{circle, probData[[i]]}], {i, 1, Length@probData}];
```

As you can see I have used Table[] a lot. When **Length@circle** becomes large, then this approach becomes slow (at least on my PC with MMA 12.2). What are some efficient alternatives to compute **dataToPlot**?

**UPDATE**

The problem I want to solve is to obtain the cumulative distribution function for the ratio  **N1/f(s1) + N2/f(s2)**, where N1 and N2 are constants and f(s1) and f(s2) are `LogNormal[]` distributions. The way I have done it above is to use `Table[]` to loop through the various values of N2, f(s1) and f(s2).

Comment: When you find yourself writing an expression like `Table[f[ array[[i]] ]. {i, 1, Length[array]}]`, you can typically rework this into a `Map` operation like `f /@ array`.

Comment: @MarcoB, I don't think the use of  ```Map[]``` will be faster than ```Table[]```; or am I wrong?

Comment: That may depend, but see my answer for an example where the speedup is considerable. It also improves code readability. In addition, it would be helpful if you described the goal of your calculations: perhaps someone could think of a way to reframe them in a more performant way.

Comment: @MarcoB, I have added an update to the question to explain what i am trying to do. The main idea is that I am trying to obtain the cumulative distribution function of the sum of two ratios. Also, thank you for the illustration in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This vectorized version is about 100 times faster than OP's code on my M1 Max machine.

```
probData = Transpose[
     Dot[
      UnitStep[
       Plus[
        ConstantArray[900000./nDist1 - 1., Length[circle]],
        ArrayReshape[
         KroneckerProduct[circle, 1./nDist2], 
         Join[{Length[circle]}, Dimensions[nDist2]]]
        ]
       ],
      ConstantArray[1./Length[values], Length[values]]
      ]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.044559

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on my suggestion in comments, here's an example where `Map`ping a function is, in fact, rather significantly faster than a `Table` iteration:

```
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10000000, 3}];

RepeatedTiming[mapped = Mean /@ data;]
(* Out: {0.940177, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[table = Table[Mean[data[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];]
(* Out: {1.84317, Null} *)

mapped == table
(* Out: True *)
```

Comment: Use 'Table[Mean[row], {row, data}]' instead for much closer results.

Comment: @Alan I think I don't understand your comment. Your approach is faster than the OP's, but still slower than `Map`, by roughly 25%. OP was looking for something faster than their approach to `Table` iterations. `Map` is faster than your approach or theirs, at least in this example :-)

Comment: It does not close the gap completely, but it closes most of it. It is (in my view) a much fairer comparison. Fwiw.

Comment: @Alan, even though your comment did not answer the question, I have not used ```Table[]``` like this before. Thank you for the info.

Comment: And we chould not forget to comare against `vectorized = data . ConstantArray[1./3., 3]`.